# passing additional parameter to System.Action, C#

Tags: c#, delegates, action

Well, I have a button in library that looks like following:

```
    public class Button  {
       public event Action<UIButtonX> onClicked;
       //
       // when button clicked, on OnClicked method is called
       //
       protected virtual void OnClicked () {
            if (onClicked != null) onClicked (this);
       }
    }
```

When i want to handle button click, i'm writing something like:

```
button.onClicked += delegate{
  //do something
}
```

or

```
button.onClicked += HandleButtonClick;

void HandleButtonClick(UIButton obj){
}
```

Now I want to pass parameter to anonymous delegate, like

```
button.onClicked += delegate(UIButton obj, int id) {
 //do something with id
}
```

but compiler doesn't allow this. How to deal that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Who would decide on what the value of `id` is if that were possible? The framework code that invokes the delegate certainly doesn't have any idea about your `id`. There is certainly a legal way to do what you want, but you need to think on a broader scope.

Comment: Who passes id to the delegate?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to explain. We have an extra data, that button doesn't know, something like **int data[];**. and button.onClicked handler looks like
button.onClicked += delegate {
  System.Console.Write(data[id]);
}  that id must come to delegate from outside.

Comment: Looks like this is design issue to expose event as Action, for this purposes always was used signarute of standard event handler with EventArgs as second parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look of things you need to do something like this:

```
public class Button
{
    public event Action<UIButtonX, int> onClicked;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnClicked ()
    {
        var e = this.onClicked;
        if (e != null)
        {
            e(this, this.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can add your handler:

```
button.onClicked += (button, id) => { /* code here */ }
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use events instead of actions, consider reading some of the following similar qustions: [event Action<> vs event EventHandler<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431359/event-action-vs-event-eventhandler) and [C# Action/Delegate Style Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120670/c-action-delegate-style-question)

And folowing article is quite helpful for understanding differences between this approaches:
http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html

Hope it would be useful to you.